# Update field on the same table in MySql db

Tags: mysql

In the table `doTable` I need to set the field `Priority` to `1` where these conditions are present for a single `CBT_ID`:

1. CEO > 0
2. SUM(CE_TOT) > 50

And I have tried this sql query without success because I have error.

```
mysql> UPDATE `doTable` pd
INNER JOIN `doTable` pd2 ON (
    pd.CBT_ID = pd2.CBT_ID
    AND pd.CEO > 0
    AND SUM(pd.CE_TOT) > 50
)
SET pd.Priority = 1;
1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use aggregation function like `sum` in `where` clause. It's difficult to write a query without knowing table structure but you can try the following one if there are more than one row with the same CBT_ID:

```
UPDATE `doTable`
SET Priority = 1 
where CBT_ID in 
    (select CBT_ID from `doTable` 
     where CEO > 0 
     group by CBT_ID 
     having SUM(CE_TOT) > 50
     );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this SQL

```
UPDATE doTable
SET Priority = 1
WHERE (
SELECT *
FROM doTable
WHERE CEO > 0
AND SUM(CE_TOT) > 50
);
```

If you get an error try changing the AND to HAVING.

Or run two queries at once

```
UPDATE doTable SET Priority=1 WHERE CEO > 0;
UPDATE doTable SET Priority=1 WHERE SUM(CE_TOT) > 50;
```

Comment: Thanks but i have the same error : **1111 - Invalid use of group function**

Comment: Do you need both conditions to be met for priority to be 1? If not then the second solution should work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UPDATE `doTable` AS r
JOIN (
    SELECT
        CBT_ID,
        SUM(CE_TOT) AS q,
        CEO
    FROM
        `doTable`
    WHERE
        CEO > 0
    GROUP BY
        CBT_ID
    HAVING
        q > 50
) AS grp ON r.CBT_ID = grp.CBT_ID
SET r.Priority = 1
WHERE
    grp.CEO > 0
AND grp.q > 50;
```